# Angular material setting md-select selected value

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to set md-select's selected value, but I'm experiencing a problem.

When I open the page, I need to see the stock's pre-set category, but I can't see it. Instead, the same category is set for all of them. I also can't change the category when I select another one

I'm using Angular 1.5.5 & Angular Material 1.1.0

Thanks to @Pankaj Parkar, I got closer.

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRayNP?editors=1010

HTML

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/liste-app.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="ListApp" ng-controller="ListAppController">
  <div id="main">

    <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
      <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <span>9 Feb 2017</span>
    </h2>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div layout="row" flex>

      <div flex="100" layout-padding>
        <div layout="row" flex>
          <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light green">
            <h5 class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span class="align">Stocks & Categories</span>
          </h5>
          </md-toolbar>
        </div>
        <div layout="column" flex="50">
          <md-list-item id="{{stock.stock}}" layout="row" ng-repeat="stock in stocks">
            <div flex="20">{{stock.stock}}</div>
            <div flex="70">
              <md-input-container>
                <label>Category</label>
                <md-select ng-model="stock.someOtherVal" style="min-width: 200px;" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
                  <md-option ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-value="category">{{category.value}}
                  </md-option>
                </md-select>
              </md-input-container>
            </div>

          </md-list-item>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/list-app.js"></script>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('ListApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate']);

angular.module('ListApp').controller("ListAppController", [
  "$scope",
  "$http",
  "$filter",
  "$timeout",
  function($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout) {

    $scope.stocks = [];

    $scope.categories = [{
      id: 1,
      value: "Volatile"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: "Normal"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      value: "High Volume"
    }];

    /*$http.get('http://localhost/liststocks').then(function(response) {
      $scope.stocks = response.data;
    });*/

    // $http.get mock is below, I use $http.get but this is codepen, so...

    // id = STOCK ID
    // category = CATEGORY ID
    $scope.stocks = [{
      "id": 1,
      "category": 3,
      "stock": "AAPL"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "category": 3,
      "stock": "TSLA"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "category": 1,
      "stock" : "SKYS"
    }];

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused by your re-use of some of your attribute/variable names like "stock" and "id", I believe they caused some of your problems so I renamed them.  Then I changed the ng-model on the md-select to point at the categoryId attribute.  After that I removed the "ng-model-options" on your md-select and everything looks good now.

Javascript:

```
$scope.stocks = [{
  "stockId": 1,
  "categoryId": 3,
  "stockTicker": "AAPL"
}, {
  "stockId": 2,
  "categoryId": 3,
  "stockTicker": "TSLA"
}, {
  "stockId": 3,
  "categoryId": 1,
  "stockTicker" : "SKYS"
}];
```

HTML:

```
    <md-list-item id="{{stock.stockTicker}}" layout="row" ng-repeat="stock in stocks">
        <div flex="20">{{stock.stockTicker}}</div>
        <div flex="70">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Category</label>
            <md-select ng-model="stock.categoryId" style="min-width: 200px;">
              <md-option ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-value="category.id">{{category.value}}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
```

Here's the [Forked pen](http://codepen.io/james_bell/pen/VPVwoZ)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `selected="selected"` attribute from `md-option` element. It is causing to to show all element as selected.

```
<div layout="column" flex="50">
  <md-list-item id="{{stock.stock}}" layout="row" ng-repeat="stock in stocks">
    <div flex="20">{{stock.stock}}</div>
    <div flex="70">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Category</label>
        <md-select ng-model="stock.someOtherVal" style="min-width: 200px;" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
          <md-option ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-value="category">{{category.value}}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
    </div>

  </md-list-item>
</div>
```

[**Forked Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRayNP?editors=1010)

Comment: The dupe problem has been solved thanks to your suggestion, but the same category is set for all of them now. I also can't change the category when I select another one.

Comment: Thanks for the forked pen, it's very close to what I'm trying to achieve. How can I make the pre-set categories selected so I can see their pre-defined values? For instance, AAPL's is 3 (High Volume), SKYS's is 1 (Volatile), etc :)